# How to rebind vim commands in Vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

So I'm having trouble rebinding vim commands in vscode.
I want to bind `W` to `w` in normal mode.

`noremap W w` <- line in vim

This is what I have after looking at the vscode/vim docs, but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
"vim.normalModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
        {
            "before": ["W"],
            "commands": [
                ":w"
            ]
        }
    ]
```

hopefully after this `w` also saves the file, I just want to also rebind `W` to also save.

Comment: I have the same question, and find an [issue](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/2903) about it, but it seems that these is not a good solution. To make thing easier, I just use ZZ to save file instead as mentioned in VSCodeVim's readme.